# Can I POST a form to an external URL and also my own server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, post, submit, external-url

In rails, can I get a form submit to send the info in the form both to an external URL, and also post to my own server, all with one click from the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the create or update actions in the controller, after the save action:

```
require 'net/http'
Net::HTTP.get('www.example.com', '/index.html?'+params)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it yourself, preferably by triggering the external request after you're done with your procedure, hopefully using message queuing.